# dalvikvm(601): VM aborting ERROR?

Tags: android

```
12-16 12:53:08.021: W/KeyCharacterMap(601): No keyboard for id 0
12-16 12:53:08.021: W/KeyCharacterMap(601): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
12-16 12:53:20.641: W/dalvikvm(601): JNI WARNING: jarray 0x405b6248 points to non-array object (Ljava/lang/String;)
12-16 12:53:20.700: I/dalvikvm(601): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
12-16 12:53:20.740: I/dalvikvm(601):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x405210e0 self=0x2a3e28
12-16 12:53:20.740: I/dalvikvm(601):   | sysTid=609 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2771288`enter code here`
12-16 12:53:20.740: I/dalvikvm(601):   | schedstat=( 1241248392 1343902211 147 )
12-16 12:53:20.759: I/dalvikvm(601):   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)
12-16 12:53:20.769: I/dalvikvm(601):   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)
12-16 12:53:20.769: I/dalvikvm(601):   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.loadUrl(BrowserFrame.java:246)
12-16 12:53:20.769: I/dalvikvm(601):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.loadUrl(WebViewCore.java:1570)
12-16 12:53:20.769: I/dalvikvm(601):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$1400(WebViewCore.java:53)
12-16 12:53:20.769: I/dalvikvm(601):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:956)
12-16 12:53:20.790: I/dalvikvm(601):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-16 12:53:20.790: I/dalvikvm(601):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-16 12:53:20.800: I/dalvikvm(601):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
12-16 12:53:20.809: I/dalvikvm(601):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
12-16 12:53:20.809: E/dalvikvm(601): VM aborting
```

I wish my English is bad for the first excuse.
Android 2.2 devices, 2.3+ devices, but it is not no trouble giving this error after the application closes

```
@Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {


        super.onPageFinished(view, url);



            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {



                            a.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { "
                                    + "document.getElementById('-----').value='"
                                    +"----"
                                    + "';})()");
                            a.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {document.getElementById('-----').value='"
                                    + "------"+ "';})()");
                            //At this point fails and shuts down after a short period of time continue to work

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        // Log.e("pagefinis>>>", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            });


    }
```

Thank you for helping....

---

not calculated if it

```
a.loadUrl ("javascript: window.HHtml.HtmlGonder"
+ "(Document.getElementsByTagName ('html') [0]. InnerHTML );");
```

How can I solve this problem, the error is due to the satırıdan?

Answer (score 2):

It's the problem with emulator, not with your code, as some of the GPS functionality is supported only in Google 14 API (Reverse Geocoding, etc.) same way this also works with some emulator alone

Answer (score 0):

I dont do javascript, but basically one of your javascript variables in your webview is returning a null or non array value.

You also never null check:

```
 document.getElementById('-----')
```

(what if this was not present?)

You can ignore the warnings about keyboard in your log, this is standard output.